# How to send apns-collapse-id through FCM in Golang with the official lib

Tags: ios, firebase, go, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send collapsible messages through FCM using the official messaging lib in Golang: https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go/messaging.

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages) is pretty clear:

> Set the appropriate parameter in your message request: collapseKey on Android and apns-collapse-id on Apple

For Android it's clear, there's a collapse_key field. However, I'm unable to figure out how to send the apns-collapse-id for Apple. There's no field for this on the message.

I read other solutions, but they propose using a different sdk. If possible I'd use the recommended one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apns-collapse-id` as a key in the `Headers` field of [APNSConfig struct](https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go/messaging?utm_source=godoc#APNSConfig) when configuring your [messaging.Message](https://type%20APNSConfig%20struct%20%7B%20%09Headers%20%20%20%20map%5Bstring%5Dstring%20%60json:%22headers,omitempty%22%60%20%09Payload%20%20%20%20*APNSPayload%20%20%20%20%20%20%60json:%22payload,omitempty%22%60%20%09FCMOptions%20*APNSFCMOptions%20%20%20%60json:%22fcm_options,omitempty%22%60%20%7D) for the [Send method](https://type%20APNSConfig%20struct%20%7B%20%09Headers%20%20%20%20map%5Bstring%5Dstring%20%60json:%22headers,omitempty%22%60%20%09Payload%20%20%20%20*APNSPayload%20%20%20%20%20%20%60json:%22payload,omitempty%22%60%20%09FCMOptions%20*APNSFCMOptions%20%20%20%60json:%22fcm_options,omitempty%22%60%20%7D).

```
type APNSConfig struct {
    Headers    map[string]string `json:"headers,omitempty"`   <- here
    Payload    *APNSPayload      `json:"payload,omitempty"`
    FCMOptions *APNSFCMOptions   `json:"fcm_options,omitempty"`
}
```

I've just tested it and it replace any previous unopenned notification with the same `apns-collapse-id` on the locked screen of my iOS device.